# Convert specific columns to list and then create json

Tags: python, json, pandas, list

I have a spreadsheet like the following:
[image]

As you can see, there are multiple "tags" columns like this: "tags_0", "tags_1", "tags_2".
And they can be more.

I'm trying to find all the "tags", and put them inside a list using panda's data frame. And eventually, put them inside an array of "tags" inside a json file.

I thought of using regex, but I can't find a way to apply it.

This is the function I'm using to output the json file. I added the tags array for reference:

```
def convert_products():
    read_exc = pd.read_excel('./data/products.xlsx')
    df = pd.DataFrame(read_exc)
    all_data = []

    for i in range(len(df)):
        js = {
            "sku": df['sku'][i],
            "brand": df['brand'][i],
            "tags": [?]
        }

        all_data.append(js)

    json_object = json.dumps(all_data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

    with open("./data/products.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json_object)
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that in a much easier way by doing something like this...

```
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx')

tags_columns = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith("tags_")]

df["tags"] = df[tags_columns].values.tolist()

df[["sku","brand","tags"]].to_json("test.json",orient="records")
```

You can try other json orientation if you want: `["index","columns","split","records","values","table"]`. Check them in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: Perhaps `col.startswith('tags_')`?

Comment: I used your method to the part "toList", and it worked and preserved the rest of my code. and I used dropna(), but it didn't drop empty values, and now I have NaN in my json.
Any idea how to drop them? thanks

Comment: If you want to drop the missing values:

Option 1: remove rows with one or more missing values
`df = df.dropna(how="any")`

Option 2: remove rows with all missing values
`df = df.dropna(how="all")`

Answer (score 0):

First You can get all the columns as a list

```
list(df.columns.values)
```

Now you can search for all columns names which contains *tags_* inside this list, once you get all the columns names which is for tags, you can loop through this list and retrieve specific tag value for specific row and put inside a list
And can pass into json object.

```
For each row in dataframe:
    tagList =[]
    for tagColumn in tagColumnList:
        tagList.append(df[tagColumn][i])
    
   .... Your code for creating json object...
 Pass this tagList for tags key in json object
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df[['sku', 'brand']], 
                 df.filter(regex='^tags_').agg(list, axis=1).rename('tags')],
                axis=1).to_json(orient='records', indent=2)
print(out)

# Output
[
  {
    "sku":"ADX112",
    "brand":"ADX",
    "tags":[
      "art",
      "frame",
      "painting"
    ]
  }
]
```